# Which scripture mentions the prasthanatrayi?

Tags: scripture

I am looking for the mentions of prasthanatrayi and its books by any of the ancient scholars and scriptures but I am unable to find even one mention... I will appriciate the help of the esteemed members here with this matter.

Comment: Apparently no scripture does .. it is a man made terminology and that too created in recent history

Comment: Extemely helpful answer! I was sensing that..... Thank you for replying.